# MDBottomNavigation tabs positioned incorrectly

Tags: python, kivy-language, bottomnavigationview, kivymd

I am currently working on an app which has several Screens (I used ScreenManager for this). There is however, one Screen called TravelManagerWindow, which has an MDBottomNavigation widget as well, for one MDBottomNavigationItem (or screen) will be for travel expense requests and the other for providing evidence of such expenses after the trip.

The problem is that once I enter my TravelManagerWindow, the tabs of the MDBottomNavigation widget are positioned incorrectly. Nevertheless, after I resize the whole app window manually, the tab positions change to their desired location. Is there a way to ensure the tabs are rendered correctly from the beginning? I've been searching for various days for solutions and still have not been able to solve my problem.

Relevant code is the following:

```
<TravelManagerWindow>:
    name:'travelManager'
    on_enter: root.set_expansion_panel()
    on_enter: root.set_expansion_panel_2()


    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDBottomNavigation:
            id: bottom_Navigation

            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                text: 'Solicitud de Gastos'
                name: 'solicitudes'
                halign:'center'
                icon: 'plus'
    
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                text: 'Comprobacion de Gastos'
                name: 'comprobacion'
                halign:'center'
                icon: 'format-list-checks'
```

The original position of the tabs, when entering to the screen is:
[image: Original position before resizing]

The desired position, after resizing is:
[image: MDBottomNavigations tabs after resizing (desired position)]

**EDIT**

I included a minimal reproducible example. The code is the following:

Python file:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class LoginWindow(Screen):
    pass

class BottomNavigationWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

ScreenManager().add_widget(LoginWindow(name='login'))
ScreenManager().add_widget(BottomNavigationWindow(name='BottomNav'))

class reprod_example2(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"
        return WindowManager()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    reprod_example2().run()
```

KV file:

```
<WindowManager>:
    LoginWindow:
    BottomNavigationWindow:

<LoginWindow>:
    name: 'login'
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: 'Enter'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        size_hint: None, None
        on_release:
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'up'
            root.manager.current = 'BottomNav'

<BottomNavigationWindow>:
    name:'BottomNav'

    MDBoxLayout:

        MDBottomNavigation:
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                text: 'Page 1'
                name: 'page1'
                MDLabel:
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
                    text: 'This is page one'

            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                text: 'Page 2'
                name: 'page2'
                MDLabel:
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
                    text: 'This is page two'
```

[image]

In my minimal reproducible example I find the same error. The MDBottomNavigation is positioned incorrectly. Manually reshaping the window fixes the problem. However I want the MDBottom Navigation to be drawn correctly since the beginning.

Any word of advice is greatly appreciated
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I simply resized the window before entering the screen where the MDBottomNavigation is located:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window

def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
    Window.size = (Window.width + 1, Window.height + 1)
    Window.size = (Window.width - 1, Window.height - 1)
```

Comment: Though id does not seems like model solution it also worked for me. Thanks!